# OpenCV filtering with dynamic kernel size

Tags: opencv, image-processing, filtering, gaussianblur

In OpenCV, I would like to implement a Gaussian blur where the kernel size depends on a parameter, such as distance from a certain point in the image. I.e., I would like to achieve a selective focus effect, with stronger blur the longer the distance between the blurred point and the selected focus point. Is there a way to do this without iterating over the image myself?

I briefly tried with creating circular concentric image masks, blurring each with a different kernel size, but that seemed to introduce visible edges between the circles.

Comment: No, you need to write your own function.

Comment: Can you explain why u r trying to achieve this? That might help us in finding some other way.

Comment: For purely aesthetical reasons, I am trying to abstract a picture by blurring the further I get away from a defined region. Similar to a tilt shift or circular tilt shit effect in photography. So no hidden agenda in what I am trying to achieve. I am using Python with OpenCV so if the effect can be achieved in NumPy/SciPy instead that would also work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to improve a variable lens blur algorithm in Python OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72750870/how-to-improve-a-variable-lens-blur-algorithm-in-python-opencv)