# How to improve a variable lens blur algorithm in Python OpenCV?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, blur

I want to emulate the blur of a cheap camera lens (like [Holga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holga)).
Blur is very weak close to the photo center.
And it's getting more decisive close to corners.

I wrote the code and it works in general.

Input image:

[image: Input image]

Result image:

[image: Result image].

But I feel that it could be done better and faster.
I've found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922692/opencv-filtering-with-dynamic-kernel-size) but it still has no answer.

**How to improve an algorithm speed and avoid iteration over pixels?**

UPDATE:
It's not the same as standard Gaussian or 2D filter blur with constant kernel size.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import requests
from tqdm import tqdm
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

def blur(img=None, blur_radius=None, test=False):
    # test image loading
    if img is None:
        test=True
        print('test mode ON')
        print('loading image...')
        url = r'http://www.lenna.org/lena_std.tif'
        resp = requests.get(url, stream=True).raw
        img = np.asarray(bytearray(resp.read()), dtype="uint8")
        img = cv2.imdecode(img, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        cv2.imwrite('img_input.png', img)
        print('image loaded')

    # channels splitting
    img_lab = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
    l, a, b = cv2.split(img_lab)
    if test:
        cv2.imwrite('l_channel.png', l)
        print('l channel saved')

    # make blur map 
    height, width = l.shape[:2]
    center = np.array([height/2, width/2])
    diag = ((height / 2) ** 2 + (width / 2) ** 2) ** 0.5
    blur_map = np.linalg.norm(
        np.indices(img.shape[:2]) - center[:,None,None] + 0.5,
        axis = 0
    )

    if blur_radius is None:
        blur_radius = int(max(height, width) * 0.03)

    blur_map = blur_map / diag 
    blur_map = blur_map * blur_radius
    if test:
        blur_map_norm = cv2.normalize(blur_map, None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX, cv2.CV_32F)
        cv2.imwrite('blur_map.png', blur_map_norm)
        print('blur map saved')

    # very inefficient blur algorithm!!!
    l_blur = np.copy(l)
    for x in tqdm(range(width)):
        for y in range(height):
            kernel_size = int(blur_map[y, x])
       
            if kernel_size == 0:
                l_blur[y, x] = l[y, x]
                continue
            
            kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (kernel_size, kernel_size))
            cut = l[
                max(0, y - kernel_size):min(height, y + kernel_size),
                max(0, x - kernel_size):min(width, x + kernel_size)
            ]

            if cut.shape == kernel.shape:
                cut = (cut * kernel).mean()
            else:
                cut = cut.mean()

            l_blur[y, x] = cut
    if test: cv2.imwrite('l_blur.png', l_blur); print('l_blur saved')
    if test: print('done')
    return l_blur

blur()
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Defocus filter is a flat circle in the spatial domain, but only for very large circles can you get a smooth digital approximation. So it is better approximated as a sinc function in the Fourier domain. See rect vs sinc at https://www.thefouriertransform.com/pairs/fourier.php for example

Comment: The black border may simply be due to your convolution without unfolding (or repeating or duplicating) the image at the border by half the kernel size plus 1. If you are simply using a circle in the spatial domain, you might as well just draw it as white filled on a black background image and then do the cv2.filter2D(). That would be faster than iterating over each pixel in the image. You also get the benefit of the padding. See borderType at https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga27c049795ce870216ddfb366086b5a04

Comment: What shape is the profile of your filter? It does inverted Gaussian. Lens defocus is not a Gaussian blur. I do not know what other distortions besides lens defocus is included in a Holga camera. Do you have any references to guide your implementation?

Comment: @fmw42
thanks for the Fourier transformation hint
considering filter 2D: of course, I've tried it but it works only for constant kernel size. In my code I use square 'cut' kernel but have no idea to cut round or oval kernels

Comment: Make constant white circle or ellipse on black background as your kernel. You can draw circles for example. To get an ellipse, stretch further along one axis. You can then do the dft, apply by multiplication in the Fourier domain, then do idft back. That would be faster than processing pixel by pixel as you do.

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75961394/make-image-more-blurry-when-farther-from-center/75965196#75965196 (uses a pyramid scheme for speed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to implement a filter where the kernel is different for every pixel is to create the kernel for each pixel and apply it in a loop, like OP's code does. The Fourier transform does not apply to this case. Python is a very slow language, the same algorithm implemented in a compiled language would be much faster. Unless there is some predefined structure in how the kernel is created at each pixel, there is no way to reduce the complexity of the algorithm.

For example, the uniform filter with a square kernel (commonly called the "box" filter) can be computed based on the integral image, using only 4 additions per pixel. This implementation should be able to choose a different kernel size at each pixel without any additional cost.

DIPlib has an implementation of an adaptive Gaussian filter [disclaimer: I'm an author of DIPlib, but I did not implement this functionality]. [Here is the documentation](https://diplib.org/diplib-docs/nonlinear.html#dip-AdaptiveGauss-dip-Image-CL-dip-ImageConstRefArray-CL-dip-Image-L-dip-FloatArray-CL-dip-UnsignedArray-CL-dip-dfloat--dip-UnsignedArray-CL-dip-String-CL-dip-String-CL).
This filter applies a Gaussian filter, but the Gaussian kernel is scaled and rotated differently at every pixel.

Lens blur is not a Gaussian, but it's not easy to see the difference by eye in most cases; the difference matters only if there is a very small dot with high contrast.

OP's case would be implemented as follows:

```py
import diplib as dip

img = dip.ImageRead('examples/trui.ics')

blur_map = dip.CreateRadiusSquareCoordinate(img.Sizes())
blur_map /= dip.Maximum(blur_map)

img_blur = dip.AdaptiveGauss(img, [0, blur_map], sigmas=[5])
```

(the `blur_map` here is defined differently, I chose a quadratic function of the distance to the center, because I think it looks really nice; use `dip.CreateRadiusCoordinate()` to reproduce OP's map).

[image: input image] [image: output image]

I've chosen a maximum blur of 5 (this is the sigma, in pixels, of the Gaussian, not the footprint of the kernel), and `blur_map` here scales this sigma with a factor between 0 in the middle and 1 at the corners of the image.

Another interesting effect would be as follows, with increasing blur tangential to each circle centered in the middle of the image, with very little blur radially:

```py
angle_map = dip.CreatePhiCoordinate(img.Sizes())
img_blur = dip.AdaptiveGauss(img, [angle_map, blur_map], sigmas=[8,1])
```

[image: output image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to apply (uniform, non-varying) lens defocus blur in Python/OpenCV by transforming both the image and filter to the Fourier (frequency) domain.

- Read the input
- Take dft of input to transform to Fourier domain
- Draw a white filled circle on a black background the size of the input as a mask (filter kernel). This is the defocus kernel in the spatial domain, i.e. a circular rect function.
- Blur the circle slightly to anti-alias the edge
- Roll the mask so that the center is at the origin (top left corner) and normalize so that the sum of values = 1
- Take dft of mask to transform to Fourier domain where its amplitude profile is a jinx function.
- Multiply the two dft images to apply the blur
- Take the idft of the product to transform back to spatial domain
- Get the magnitude of the real and imaginary components of the product, clip and convert to uint8 as the result
- Save the result

Input:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# read input and convert to grayscale
img = cv2.imread('lena_512_gray.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# do dft saving as complex output
dft_img = np.fft.fft2(img, axes=(0,1))

# create circle mask
radius = 32
mask = np.zeros_like(img)
cy = mask.shape[0] // 2
cx = mask.shape[1] // 2
cv2.circle(mask, (cx,cy), radius, 255, -1)[0]

# blur the mask slightly to antialias
mask = cv2.GaussianBlur(mask, (3,3), 0)

# roll the mask so that center is at origin and normalize to sum=1
mask_roll = np.roll(mask, (256,256), axis=(0,1))
mask_norm = mask_roll / mask_roll.sum() 

# take dft of mask
dft_mask_norm = np.fft.fft2(mask_norm, axes=(0,1))

# apply dft_mask to dft_img
dft_shift_product = np.multiply(dft_img, dft_mask_norm)

# do idft saving as complex output
img_filtered = np.fft.ifft2(dft_shift_product, axes=(0,1))

# combine complex real and imaginary components to form (the magnitude for) the original image again
img_filtered = np.abs(img_filtered).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)

cv2.imshow("ORIGINAL", img)
cv2.imshow("MASK", mask)
cv2.imshow("FILTERED DFT/IFT ROUND TRIP", img_filtered)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# write result to disk
cv2.imwrite("lena_512_gray_mask.png", mask)
cv2.imwrite("lena_dft_numpy_lowpass_filtered_rad32.jpg", img_filtered)
```

Mask - Filter Kernel In Spatial Domain:

[image]

Result for Circle Radius=4:

[image]

Result for Circle Radius=8:

[image]

Result for Circle Radius=16:

[image]

Result for Circle Radius=32

[image]:

**ADDITION**

Using OpenCV for the dft, etc rather than Numpy, the above becomes:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# read input and convert to grayscale
img = cv2.imread('lena_512_gray.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# do dft saving as complex output
dft_img = cv2.dft(np.float32(img), flags = cv2.DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT)

# create circle mask
radius = 32
mask = np.zeros_like(img)
cy = mask.shape[0] // 2
cx = mask.shape[1] // 2
cv2.circle(mask, (cx,cy), radius, 255, -1)[0]

# blur the mask slightly to antialias
mask = cv2.GaussianBlur(mask, (3,3), 0)

# roll the mask so that center is at origin and normalize to sum=1
mask_roll = np.roll(mask, (256,256), axis=(0,1))
mask_norm = mask_roll / mask_roll.sum() 

# take dft of mask
dft_mask_norm = cv2.dft(np.float32(mask_norm), flags = cv2.DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT)

# apply dft_mask to dft_img
dft_product = cv2.mulSpectrums(dft_img, dft_mask_norm, 0)

# do idft saving as complex output, then clip and convert to uint8
img_filtered = cv2.idft(dft_product, flags=cv2.DFT_SCALE+cv2.DFT_REAL_OUTPUT)
img_filtered = img_filtered.clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)

cv2.imshow("ORIGINAL", img)
cv2.imshow("MASK", mask)
cv2.imshow("FILTERED DFT/IFT ROUND TRIP", img_filtered)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# write result to disk
cv2.imwrite("lena_512_gray_mask.png", mask)
cv2.imwrite("lena_dft_opencv_defocus_rad32.jpg", img_filtered)
```

Comment: The question is not worded clearly, but OP is looking for variable kernel size, the edges of the desired result image are blurred more strongly than the middle.

Comment: `@Cris Luengo`. Thanks for the clarification. Sorry, I misunderstood. Hope my post will be useful anyway.

Comment: @CrisLuengo thanks for the comment! It's a point!
I've improved my algorithm (quite brute but it works) so the last question is a **SPEED** because I still have iteration over pixels. Maybe you got some ideas what to read to make it better?

Comment: @fmw42 Thanks again, I'll try to think in the **dft** direction.
I think it could be useful. Maybe you know how to avoid iterations in my new algorithm proposal?

Comment: @maxim You cannot use the DFT (=FFT) for anything that is not a convolution. If the kernel changes pixel to pixel, it’s not a convolution.

Comment: `@Maxim`. Sorry, I misunderstood your question. My approach applies a uniform (non-varying) defocus blur. As CrisLuengo, said, it does not apply to spatially varying blurs. The only thing that I can think of might be (????) to do many uniform blurs via my approach and blend them spatially gradually as the radius increases from the center. I do not know of that is what you want or if it is even a reasonable approach.

Comment: @fmw42 thanks for an answer! It's a little bit different from what I want but I've started to read on Fourier transform and advanced gauss kernels.

Comment: `@Maxim` Note that a gaussian kernel (blur) is not the same as camera defocus. A Gaussian kernel in the spatial domain transforms to a Gaussian kernel (different width) in the frequency domain, which is always positive. A camera defocus is a flat circle in the spatial domain and transforms to a Jinc function in the frequency domain, which oscillates positive and negative.