# Bokeh-like Blur with Mask as Intensity of Blur Radius

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I know how to Gaussian blur with Pillow, but can't track how to mask it by intensity of the radius value with a mask.

I am using MiDaS package to produce depth maps form 2D images. What I want to do is be able to blur the original image by the depth mask as a pseudo depth of field.

Here is a visual demonstration of the result I'm after with CV2 or Pillow (I don't understand which can do what I'm after.)

[image: Fake DOF Example]

Note: I'm sorry if this is considered junk, I've sat on this question for a month. I tried scouring the net for something like this, and all I found was Poor Man's Portrait Mode which I could not get to work, and also would be reproducing depth maps when I already have them from my script and used for the 3D image creation.

**Edit:**

I did come up with this, using composite Not sure why I didn't take note of it before. Though I have to say, the results aren't too great. I think I really do need to emulate some sort of shape blur like bokeh.

```
sharpen = 3
boxBlur = 5

oimg = Image.open('2.png').convert('RGB')
width, height = oimg.size
mimg = Image.open('2_depth.png').resize((width, height)).convert('L')

bimg = oimg.filter(ImageFilter.BoxBlur(int(boxBlur)))
bimg = bimg.filter(ImageFilter.BLUR)
for i in range(sharpen):
    bimg = bimg.filter(ImageFilter.SHARPEN)

rimg = Image.composite(oimg, bimg, mimg)
```

- Basically get your image, and mask, ensure the mask matches the image (I had a issue where images didn't match, but were the same size, just saved different from 2 saved the same way)
- Blur your image to a new variable, however you like, Gaussian, etc. Gaussian was too soft for me. Add whatever extra filtering you want
- Composite the results together, using depth map as a mask for composite.

**Note:** If someone knows how to achieve a different sort of blur that mimics bokeh, I'd like to know, and have adjusted the question title. I read about a discBlur but couldn't find anything for PIL/CV2.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to improve a variable lens blur algorithm in Python OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72750870/how-to-improve-a-variable-lens-blur-algorithm-in-python-opencv) — The question is not identical, but closely related. My answer there should answer this question too.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Oh wow, that circle blur thingy looks pretty close to a lens blur you'd get in photoshop or something for a DOF blur. Thank you. Thay may work better then what I have. 

It's strange I have found so many references to diskBlur/discBlur on Google with Python but the repo either doesn't have what it advertises, or is strangely not part of the page when it's part of it's google description.

Comment: I guess the problem with those methods is they require 1/2 channels, and thus your return is a greyscale image.

Comment: You apply the same filter to each channel individually.

Comment: Ohhh. Thank you. On a side note, I discovered that the median filter form Pillow, with a high sigma color (like 5000) and radius of 5, you get a good lens blur like effect.

Comment: The median is not the right filter for emulating optical lenses. Use linear filters (convolution).

Comment: @CrisLuengo do you have an example? I can't find any examples on doing shape blurs being the disk blur (in the above link you provided). I do want to try that out, but haven't looked into operating on the different channels.

Comment: This is quite interesting. I like the results when I use it on a face in a portrait

Comment: I have the same question. Can i start a bounty on your question?

Answer (score 0):

I’ve got only a brute-force solution with iteration over pixels: [Variable blur intensity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72750870/how-to-improve-a-variable-lens-blur-algorithm-in-python-opencv).
My code is working but not as efficiently as I want.

You can try. Open your image as input and put your depth map in the variable `blur_map`.

Comment: You're referring to the "UPDATE" code at the bottom, correct?