# Make image more blurry when farther from center

Tags: python, opencv

I'm new to OpenCV. I want to create a function that takes some focal point in an image and progressively gets more blurry as you move away from that focal point (as in, continuously more blurry, not selecting areas to be blurred and non-blurred). I kind of want to make the blur increase as continuous as possible. Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Blur the image by a large amount (maximum that you want). Create a circular ramp centered at the desired point. Use the ramp as a mask to blend between the original and the highly blurred image.

Comment: You could make your own convolution function, and then change the kernel depending on where you are in the image while applying it.  Would likely be slow, but produce nice results.

Comment: blur the entire image by increasing amounts (octaves?), then select pixels from the right "level" according to radius. with this approach, you can also blend between levels. -- this stack of blurs is required to approximate the true goal. if you just use the source and a strongly blurred version, you'd merely fade an entire band of frequencies equally, instead of each frequency fading out at its own radius. it's like seeing a triangle in a spectrogram, instead of a "gradient". -- decide what type of blur you want. there's box blur, "bokeh" (like box blur but with a circle), gaussian, ...

Comment: or... calculate the blur for each pixel (what Pete said). I don't see a cheap way to do this. it'll cost you O(r^2) per pixel

Answer (score 6):

Here's an approach that uses multiple blur strengths.

[image: output]

### Approach

- calculate versions of the image with sigma being a power of two
- calculate the desired sigma per pixel
- take logarithm base-2 for lookup
- linearly interpolate each pixel between its two levels

### Code

```
im = cv.imread(cv.samples.findFile("lena.jpg"))
(height, width) = im.shape[:2]

cx,cy = (width-1) / 2, (height-1) / 2

y,x = np.mgrid[0:height, 0:width]
distance = np.hypot(x-cx, y-cy)

sigma = distance ** 2 * 0.0002

logsigma = np.log2(sigma).astype(np.float32)
```

```
def ntimes(n, fn, *a, **kw):
    def sub(arg):
        for i in range(n):
            arg = fn(arg, *a, **kw)
        return arg
    return sub

nlayers = 8

blur_pyramid = [im]
for k in range(nlayers-1):
    blur_pyramid.append(cv.pyrDown(blur_pyramid[k]))

blur_layers = np.array([
    ntimes(k, cv.pyrUp)(blur_pyramid[k])
    for k in range(nlayers)
])

# this is faster than calculating GaussianBlur on the full-size image
```

```
# this stunt is needed because I can't figure out how to make numpy do the equivalent indexing

@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def sample_along_axis0(texture, levelmap):
    N,H,W,C = texture.shape
    out = np.empty((H,W,C), dtype=np.uint8)
    levelmap = np.clip(levelmap, 0, N-1)

    ilevelmap = np.clip(np.floor(levelmap).astype(np.int32), 0, N-2)
    flevelmap = levelmap - ilevelmap

    for y in nb.prange(H):
        for x in range(W):
            ilevel = ilevelmap[y,x]
            flevel = flevelmap[y,x]
            out[y,x] = np.clip(
                (1-flevel) * texture[ilevel,y,x] + flevel * texture[ilevel+1,y,x],
                0, 255)

    return out

composite = sample_along_axis0(blur_layers, logsigma)
```

*This code contains an "off-by-one" error in the sigma level calculation. the second level, `[1]`, corresponds to sigma=1 due to the lowpassing in `pyrDown`, however I treat it like it represents `log(sigma) == 1`, which would mean sigma=2. I think that's a fine exercise for the reader to find an appropriate place to fix this.*

Here are versions with nearest-neighbor interpolation (along levels) and with a different tint per level. You can clearly see where the levels meet. The inner ring is all "red" because that's getting no blur at all, i.e. it's level 0 (and the source image is seriously tinted red).

[image: straight without lerp]

[image: tinted, without lerp]
[image: tinted, with lerp]

### Why does that approach make sense?

Blurring is lowpassing. If you consider the plot of the spectrum of a lowpass, it falls off beyond a certain point.

[image]

For this radially varying blur, you want that cut-off point to move left/right (along the frequency axis).

If you took just the source image and a strongly blurred version of it, and then interpolate between them, that doesn't move the point left/right, it moves an entire plateau of frequencies up/down, namely those beyond the cut-off point.

In the limit, if the blurred version is very strong, it's just one flat color. You'd essentially get a vignette:

[image]

Comment: Very cool to see this done in practice.  Excellent answer here.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV.

Blur the image to the maximum desired amount. Then create a radial gradient. Then use the radial gradient to blend between the original image and the blurred image.

Input:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import math

# Define the center and radius of the circle
width = 256
height = 256
center = [128,128]
maxblur = 99
ramppow = 1.5

# read the input
img = cv2.imread('lena.png')

# blur the image to the maximum desired
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (maxblur,maxblur), sigmaX=0, sigmaY=0)

# Note [:, None] and [None, :] specify which dimension that array will specify
# Linear ramps are between 0 and 1 and have number of increments of width or height
x = np.linspace(0, 1, width)[:, None]
y = np.linspace(0, 1, height)[None, :]

# normalize the center coordinates between 0 and 1
cx = center[1]/width
cy = center[0]/height

# Set graylevel of gradient proportional to distance from center
# Note multiply by sqrt(2) so 0 to 255 goes diagonally from center
# Include non-linear ramp power function to blur faster as get farther from the center
# Linear ramp would be ramppow=1
ramppow = 1/ramppow
gradient = np.sqrt((x-cx)**2 + (y-cy)**2)
gradient = cv2.pow(gradient,ramppow)
gradient = (255*math.sqrt(2)*gradient).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)
gradient = cv2.merge([gradient,gradient,gradient])

# merge the input and blurred image using the gradient
result = ((gradient*blur.astype(np.float64) + (1-gradient)*img.astype(np.float64))/255).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)

# Save result
cv2.imwrite('lena_radial_gradient.png', gradient)
cv2.imwrite('lena_radial_gradient_blur.png', result)

# Show results
cv2.imshow('blur', blur)
cv2.imshow('gradient', gradient)
cv2.imshow('result ', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

(Non-Linear) Radial Gradient:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Preserves high frequencies far from the center, which may or may not be desirable.